# Alternatives to DTO objects in Java

Tags: java, spring, web

Are there alternatives to DTO in Java ? The problem that I can see is when there are a lot of endpoints in web application the number of classes for representing API requests and responses is huge and often that classes are similar. So, I am interested if there are any other approaches for representing requests and responses then using DTO classes ? Maybe there are approaches that doesn't require creating a lot of classes ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there are classes that are similar, consider using subclasses/inheritance to cut down on code repetition. This can apply to your situation by creating a base/common DTO for the request or response body and then extending those classes as you see fit.